# dojo AccordionPane onSelected replacement

Tags: javascript, accordion, dojo

According to the dojo docs, dijit.layout.AccordionPane is deprecated in favor of dijit.layout.ContentPane
link: http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.3.2/dijit.layout.AccordionPane

I cannot find an attribute for ContentPane that functions similarly to the AccordionPane's "onSelected" attribute. Is there another widiget or another way to use the ContentPane widget to reproduce this behavior?

I have definitely tried onClick and onFocus to no avail.

Comment: what does onSelected mean in a ContentPane?

Comment: It doesn't have any meaning. That's where I had gotten lost. onSelected had meaning for an AccordionPane and AccordionPane was deprecated in favor of ContentPane, but ContentPane didn't "understand" onSelected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, it seems that in the 1.4.0beta2 release, this is addressed with the "onShow" attribute to ContentPane. I just tested and it does work.

So for now, the AccordionPane still works as expected although it is technically deprecated.

Comment: also, you should be able to use topics on the AccordionContainer (actually, see StackContainer for docs on this).  Try subscribing to [widgetId]-selectChild.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not use deprecated AccordionPane. ContentPane's onShow does what you want.